# Are external JavaScript files for functions only?

Tags: javascript, html, function, module, external

this may sound like a stupid question but I'm a beginner in Web Developing and I have this doubt:

If I want to store my scripts in an external .js file would that be only a container of functions? For example if I try, in that file, to write some code outside of a function (something like this:)

```
var person = {
      name: "Rick",
      surname: "Sanchez",
      nephew: "Morty",
    };

    document.write(person.nephew + " is " + person.name + " " + person.surname 
    + "'s nephew");
```

that doesn't work and it doesn't write anything in the HTML.

Am I correct or that's because I'm doing something wrong?

Thx!

Comment: `document.write` is likely an issue, because it's not the 1990's any more - but, you can do whatever in an external JS file as per inline JS

Comment: You can write whatever you like in an external file pretty much, but in general as Jaromanda says, don't use document.write, that's ancient history. Instead, manipulate DOM objects (e.g. you get hold of the body object, or some div within it, or whatever, and then change that, or append to it etc). Most good tutorials would show you the correct way.

Comment: So if, instead of using document.write, I used .innerHTML to manipulate an element would that work, even if the block of code is outside of a function?

Comment: Of course it would (provided the element you are trying to access exists already), this has absolutely nothing to do with inside function or not.

Comment: That code works fine when I test it. The problem is not in the code you've provided. You need to supply a [mcve].

Comment: I think I got the error:
the reason why I wasn't able to modify elements in the external js was because I put the script src in the head so the DOM wasn't ready yet 
I will put it right before the body closes from now on. Thanks to anyone!

Answer (score -1):

As some people ahead of me said, document.write is not really the way to go anymore. You are better of grabbing (selecting) elements in the HTML document and changing them with functions like appendChild, element.innerHTML = ... and so on. 
But to answer your initial question, no, your Javascript files are not only bound to functions. You can execute logic outside of functions as well.
Try to see functions as a way to keep your logic organized, and making it easier for you to trigger specific parts of that logic when a specific event happens (a click, scroll, a form is submitted, etc)